# Hide Browse for Type options for Agurments/Variables when rehosting Workflow Designer

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

Currently I have re-hosted in my application the Windows Workflow Designer (.net 4 / C#). It works all fine.

The problem is that, in the bottom part, in the part where you can add and modify variables/arguments in your workflow, i need to be able to display only certain variable/argument types.

By default it shows string, int, object, etc. I would like to hide the "Browse for Types" option.

How can this be done? I know it is possible to hide specific items in the designer, like the parameters and imports all-together, but I have not found how to hide specific data types in the selection.

Thanks a lot in advance